# angular 4 get data from database does not work

Tags: angular

I am using angular 4 with mySql Db.

Here is my service.

service.ts

```
 getData(){
    return this.http.get('http://example/users.php').map(res=>{
      return res.json();
    }).catch(err=>{
      return err.json();
    })
  }
```

i have two pages One is Home,another one is About.

Here is my Home Component.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.API.getData().subscribe(res=>{
                console.log("dashoard",res);
    })
  }
```

Here is my result.

like this JSON.

```
[{
 "user":"name one",
 "status":"1"
},
{
 "user":"name two",
 "status":"1"
}]
```

I fetch records based on user status is 1.

i changed any values is database.

I changed `name one` user status is "0";
go to About page then click to home Page.

record length is 2.When i click ctrl+f5  record length is 1.

My problem is data retrieved.But does not get updated data.why?

I have no idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: try solution which i given , it should work ,let me know if it doesnt work for you...

Comment: can you make sure that your constructor getting called every time when you come back from about page to home page ....that is must because if you constructor is not getting called than it will not work and also check oninit method also get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one more reason of error is , you request is inside `ngOnInit` method

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.API.getData().subscribe(res=>{
                console.log("dashoard",res);
    })
  }
```

put code in Constructor

```
constructor() {
    this.API.getData().subscribe(res=>{
                console.log("dashoard",res);
    })
  }
```

service code

```
 getData(){
  let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache'
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
        });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://example/users.php',options).map(res=>{
      return res.json();
    }).catch(err=>{
      return err.json();
    })
  }
```

check this also : https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol

---

Its might be because browser does caching of your data , you need to put cache to off by using `Header` options avaiable for `Get` method.

below is code for making cache off

```
let headers = new Headers({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this._http.get("url", options).map(response => response.json());
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.i try to this i got this err Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Still i got this err.I put the code in constructor.

Comment: @GEVS - but i think you should go with Cache-control option , because that is only i think problem here

Comment: @GEVS - you used routing of angualr to move between page ... right ??

Comment: Yes.I used routing between pages

Comment: @GEVS - updated in answer add "'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'" also in header option

Comment: Any solutions?How can i fix this.: (

Comment: @PankajParkar.Thanks for ur reply.Yes I enabled CORS.

Comment: But it's does not work.How to clear cache in angular 4

Comment: @GEVS - can you make sure that your constructor getting called every time when you come back from about page to home page ....that is must because if you constructor is not getting called than it will not work and also check oninit method also get called